# Use of System.IO.Stream detected as an incompatible type when overriding FileConfigurationProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, resharper, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to create a custom [FileConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationprovider) implementation for some configuration elements in a .Net Core WebApi application.

It looks something like this..

```
public class MyProvider : FileConfigurationProvider
{
    public MyProvider(FileConfigurationSource source) : base(source) { }

    public override void Load(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
          // Stream reading things
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load stream.");
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the simplicity of this example, the override of `Load(Stream stream)` gives me an indicator in VS2017 that there is no suitable method for override. Furthermore an additional error hint states that `FileConfigurationProvider(System.IO.Stream) is not implemented`.

Extracting to a delegate using ReSharper has revealed a new hint for the call to `Load(Stream stream)` stating that `Argument type System.IO.Stream [System.IO, Version=4.1.0.0...] is not assignable to parameter of type System.IO.Stream [System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0...]`

Despite these error hints I can still successfully build and run this code.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong here?

The csproj is as follows..

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've also tried being more explicit in the framework defs...

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Which version of ReSharper?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.2

Comment: I have the same issue with `System.IO.Stream`. Looks like a bug in R#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the bug in JetBrains bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464676